# Section Indexer Overlay is not updating as the adapter's data changes

Tags: android

I have implemented Section Indexer for an Adapter class which extends BaseAdapter.
Now for the first launch Section Indexer is showing an overlay correctly. But when the contents of the list gets updated the Section Overlay does not get updated and gives ArrayOutOfBoundException. For one fix what i did is i made listview.setFastScrollEnabled(false); update the adapter contents; and then listview.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
Now what happens is overlay gets updated but the Overlay is coming to the left top of the listview. How can I fix this.

Comment: Got the same problem, no workaround yet - Android 1.5

Comment: I've filled a bug 9054 http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9054

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a small workaround which was suggested by lee.wilmot is

```
private void jiggleGrid() {

          int newWidth = flag( FLAG_THUMB_PLUS ) ?
FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT :
                  grid.getWidth() - 1;

          FrameLayout.LayoutParams l = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                          newWidth,
                          FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT
          );

          grid.setLayoutParams( l );

          toggleFlag( FLAG_THUMB_PLUS );
  }
```

flag and toggleFlag are some functions.

Call this method after setting `setFastScrollEnabled(true);`. It worked for me....

Comment: could you please show what your layout looks like? I mean XML definition. Workaround doesn't work for me.

Comment: what is FLAG_THUMB_PLUS would be really great to know

Comment: This solution doesn't work if the width is set to FILL_PARENT. If you implement this, and then say, change the orientation, the width is set incorrectly.

Answer (score 8):

Thought I'd share a ready-made version of the above workaround for a ListActivity:

```
private boolean FLAG_THUMB_PLUS = false;
private void jiggleWidth() {

    ListView view = getListView();
    if (view.getWidth() <= 0)
        return;

    int newWidth = FLAG_THUMB_PLUS ? view.getWidth() - 1 : view.getWidth() + 1;
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
    params.width = newWidth;
    view.setLayoutParams( params );

    FLAG_THUMB_PLUS = !FLAG_THUMB_PLUS;
}
```

Works for me.

Comment: This solution doesn't work if the width is set to FILL_PARENT. If you implement this, and then say, change the orientation, the width is set incorrectly.

Answer (score 5):

To make it work in all cases (especially with FILL_PARENT layout and orientation change), instead of using a ListView directly, use this class and call invalidateSectionIndexer() after your changed your Adapter.

```
class MyListView extends ListView {
    public MyListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void invalidateSectionIndexer() {
        // 1. this invalidates the Section Indexer
        super.setFastScrollEnabled(false);
        // Your adapter might be wrapped, e.g. when adding headers/footers.
        ListAdapter adapter = getAdapter();
        BaseAdapter baseAdapter = (adapter instanceof WrapperListAdapter) ?
                (BaseAdapter) ((WrapperListAdapter) adapter).getWrappedAdapter() :
                (BaseAdapter) adapter;
        baseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        super.setFastScrollEnabled(true);

        // 2. This fixes the android bug of section overlay not positioned correctly.
        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();
        super.onSizeChanged(width, height, width, height);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Above solutions are ok except for case when width is set to FILL_PARENT. To make them work for this case you should override onSizeChanged like this

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged (int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
{
    super.onSizeChanged( w , h , oldw , oldh );
    if ( mInstance.getLayoutParams().width != FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT )
    {
        mInstance.post( new Runnable()
        {   
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                mInstance.setLayoutParams( new FrameLayout.LayoutParams( FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT , FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT ) );   
            }
        });
    }
}
```

With this modification size will be ok after changing screen orientation.

Answer (score 0):

I got similar problem using **ResourceCursorAdapter** . Section indexer was not updating after new adapter was set for list or swapCursor() method for updating cursor was called. 
I tried all the solutions posted on StackOverflow without any success. Only working workaround that i found is that you need to detach/attach fragment which you want to update (you need to trigger **onCreateView()** method of fragment where you build your UI) after i update my Cursor (not CursorAdapter.. you need to update/set adapter in onCreateView() ). This worked for me. Here is code which i use to reattach fragment.

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().detach(frag).attach(frag).commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

You can also try to remove corresponding listView from layout  and that add it to layout again but i got into some issues using this approach.