# How to start Fragment from Activity?

Tags: android, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I have one Fragment:

```
ProductsFragments extends Fragment
```

and one Activity

```
AdminMenuActivity extends ActionBarActivity
```

I want to call ProductsFragments from AdminMenuActivity. I have used 2 options:

1)

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                for(int i = 0; i < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {
                    fm.popBackStack();
                }
                FragmentTransaction tx = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                tx.replace(R.id.frame_layout, android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(AdminMenuActivity.this, fragments[1]));
                tx.commit();
```

2)

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(AdminMenuActivity.this, ProductsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
```

Both are failed. I don't want to extend ProductsFragments with FragmentActivity because it doesn't give me supportedActionBar v7

So how do I call `Fragment`?

Answer (score 8):

Here is how you call a fragment from inside an Activity

```
Fragment fr = new FirstFragment();
fr.setArguments(args);
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fr);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Assuming you have fragment_place represents the following:

```
<fragment android:name="com.company.appName.fragments.FirstFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_place"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting

> Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment',
>   required: 'android.app.Fragment'

this error, check the imports, you may find the below,

```
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

delete the above imports.
Change `getFragmentManager()`to `getSupportFragmentManager()`

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager(); to
FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
```

now we can import the,

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
```