# Android Tab Bar With Navigation Controller Application

Tags: android, mobile

I'm `iOS` developer, with `iOS` I can use `UITabbarcontroller` and `UINavigatorcontroller` when I want to make Tab bar with Navigator app. Now I'm moving to Android, could you please tell me how to do this, where can I find tutorial with source code?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but using this tutorial it made everything easier. This is for the custom tab bar controller at the bottom of the screen. Since Android SDK has theres on the top you can use this link to create a custom one on the bottom.

http://kpbird.blogspot.com/2011/05/androidbottom-tabbar-control.html

Answer (score 0):

Try answer from this question
[Separate Back Stack for each tab in Android using Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987334/separate-back-stack-for-each-tab-in-android-using-fragments/12928498#12928498)

here's a github link from the thread https://github.com/iamjayanth/FragmentTabStudy