# start Activity from an other Activity with Tabs

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs

I got an app with 3 tabs. Every tab has an activity and there is one activity two manage the tabs. This works fine and I can switch from tab to tab. But now i want to switch to a tab by pressing a Button on an other tab. I tried to start the activity like this:

`final Intent openTabMainActivity = new Intent(this,TabMainActivity.class);
startActivity(openTabMainActivity);`

This starts the Activity infront of the tabs. But I only want to switch to the activity.

This is the activity to manage the tabs (I am new at Android and I got this code from a tutorial):

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    // Tab for Main
    TabSpec mainspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Main");
    // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
    mainspec.setIndicator("Main", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_main_tab));
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this, TabMainActivity.class);
    mainspec.setContent(mainIntent);

    // Tab for Graph
    TabSpec graphspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Graph");
    graphspec.setIndicator("Graph", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_graph_tab));
    Intent graphIntent = new Intent(this, TabGraphActivity.class);
    graphspec.setContent(graphIntent);

    // Tab for Option
    TabSpec optionspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Option");
    optionspec.setIndicator("Option", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_option_tab));
    Intent optionIntent = new Intent(this, TabOptionActivity.class);
    optionspec.setContent(optionIntent);


    // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
    tabHost.addTab(mainspec); 
    tabHost.addTab(graphspec); 
    tabHost.addTab(optionspec); 
}
```

}

Comment: TabActivity  is deprecated. Dont use deprecated classes. New classes give you more freedom and features.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987334/separate-back-stack-for-each-tab-in-android-using-fragments) thread might be interesting.. Better to use Fragments with Tabs than using TabActivity.

Comment: Use Fragments in tabs: http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/android-tabs-the-fragment-way/

Comment: do Fragments work on API 8?

Comment: By default NO... But google provided a there is a compatibility library which enables you to use fragments in older version.

Comment: Do I realy need to use Fragements to fix my problem? Or can someone tell me how to do it with TabActivity?

Comment: And can I realy fix my problem by using fragments? ^^

Comment: @JulianM. If my answer is helping you then please accept it.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to rate it^^.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please write below code for that, it will solve your problem.

ActivityStack.java

```
private Stack<String> stack;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (stack == null)
        stack = new Stack<String>();
    // start default activity
    push("FirstStackActivity", new Intent(this, Tab_SampleActivity.class));
}

@Override
public void finishFromChild(Activity child) {
    pop();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    pop();
}

public void push(String id, Intent intent) {
    Window window = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(id, intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
    if (window != null) {
        stack.push(id);
        setContentView(window.getDecorView());
    }
}

public void pop() {
    if (stack.size() == 1)
        finish();
    LocalActivityManager manager = getLocalActivityManager();
    manager.destroyActivity(stack.pop(), true);
    if (stack.size() > 0) {
        Intent lastIntent = manager.getActivity(stack.peek()).getIntent();
        Window newWindow = manager.startActivity(stack.peek(), lastIntent);
        setContentView(newWindow.getDecorView());
    }
}
```

TabActivity.java

```
public class TabActivity extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab_screen);
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ActivityStack.class);
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tabId").setIndicator("Temp", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.home));
        spec.setContent(intent);

        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        Intent intent1 = new Intent().setClass(this, ActivityStack.class);
        TabHost.TabSpec spec1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("tabId").setIndicator("Temp", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.invoice));
        spec1.setContent(intent1);
        tabHost.addTab(spec1);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
}
```

FirstActivity.java

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("Tab Sample Activity ");
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(getParent(), SecondActivity.class);
                ActivityStack activityStack = (ActivityStack) getParent();
                activityStack.push("SecondActivity", intent);
            }
        });
        setContentView(textView);
    }
}
```

SecondActivity.java

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("First Stack Activity ");
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(getParent(), ThirdActivity.class);
                ActivityStack activityStack = (ActivityStack) getParent();
                activityStack.push("ThirdActivity", intent);
            }
        });
        setContentView(textView);
    }
}
```

ThirdActivity.java

```
public class ThirdActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Add Below XML files into your res/layout folder.

1) tab_screen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="3dp" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</TabHost>
```

2) main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.tabsample"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".FirstActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".TabActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityStack"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SecondActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ThirdActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And see below link for more information with complete example.

[Multiple Android Activities in a TabActivity](http://androidcodeexamples.blogspot.in/2012/08/multiple-android-activities-in.html)