# How to start a new activity for a result from a tab activity in android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-tabhost, start-activity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [start Activity from an other Activity with Tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13623350/start-activity-from-an-other-activity-with-tabs)

I have a TabHost containing 3 tabs. Having Act1, Act2, Act3 for 3tabs. Now i want to start a new activity (say Act4) onclick of a button in Act1. I should see the tabs when I'm in Act4.  How can i start a new activity from my tab for a result? Please help me out.

```
 startActivityForResult(new Intent(Act1.this, Act4.class), CONSTANT);
```

The above line taking me to the Act4 screen but its not showing tabs. What should i do to see the tabs in Act4 and return back to Act1 with a result?

Comment: so what have you done so far? could you please post your code?

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava If my answer is helping you then please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try `Fragments`

[developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Answer (score 0):

Please see below link for complete example, it will solve your problem.

[Start Activity from an other Activity with Tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13623350/start-activity-from-an-other-activity-with-tabs/13624701#13624701)