# How to let TabHost show in every Activity?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [start Activity from an other Activity with Tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13623350/start-activity-from-an-other-activity-with-tabs)

[image][image]

see the following two pictures, i want to click the icon "all songs" and then jump to a playlist. but i do not know how to use TabHost and display on the playlist? How to let TabHost show in every Activity?

the code of Activity has TabHost:

```
/*package com.lxy.musicplayer.view;

import com.lxy.musicplayer.R;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class BuddleTabHostActivity extends TabActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        TabHost tab  = getTabHost();
//        LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tabhost_layout, tab.getTabContentView(),true);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.tabhost_layout);


        addIntentActivity(tab, MainActivity.class, "all songs");
        addIntentActivity(tab, MainActivity.class, "Network songs ");
        addIntentActivity(tab, MainActivity.class, "my set");

        tab.setCurrentTab(0);


    }


    private void addIntentActivity(TabHost tab,Class c,String title){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(this, c);

        TabHost.TabSpec spec = tab.newTabSpec(title);
        spec.setIndicator(title);
        spec.setContent(intent);
        tab.addTab(spec);

    }


}
*/

package com.lxy.musicplayer.view;

import com.lxy.musicplayer.R;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class BuddleTabHostActivity extends TabActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.tabhost_layout);
        //get switching object
        TabHost tab=getTabHost();
        addIntentActivity(tab, MainActivity.class,"local");
        addIntentActivity(tab, PlayActivity.class,"favorite");
        addIntentActivity(tab, PlayListActivity.class,"online");
        addIntentActivity(tab, MainActivity.class,"setting");
        //executive tab default
        tab.setCurrentTab(0);
    }

    public void addIntentActivity(TabHost tab,Class<?> c,String str){
        Intent intent=new Intent();
        intent.setClass(this, c);
        //switching object and obtain tab
        TabHost.TabSpec spec=tab.newTabSpec(str);
        //set tab information
        //turn to the page display
        spec.setIndicator(str);
        spec.setContent(intent);
        //add tabs
        tab.addTab(spec);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please write below code for that, it will solve your problem.

ActivityStack.java

```
private Stack<String> stack;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (stack == null)
        stack = new Stack<String>();
    // start default activity
    push("FirstStackActivity", new Intent(this, Tab_SampleActivity.class));
}

@Override
public void finishFromChild(Activity child) {
    pop();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    pop();
}

public void push(String id, Intent intent) {
    Window window = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(id, intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
    if (window != null) {
        stack.push(id);
        setContentView(window.getDecorView());
    }
}

public void pop() {
    if (stack.size() == 1)
        finish();
    LocalActivityManager manager = getLocalActivityManager();
    manager.destroyActivity(stack.pop(), true);
    if (stack.size() > 0) {
        Intent lastIntent = manager.getActivity(stack.peek()).getIntent();
        Window newWindow = manager.startActivity(stack.peek(), lastIntent);
        setContentView(newWindow.getDecorView());
    }
}
```

TabActivity.java

```
public class TabActivity extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab_screen);
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ActivityStack.class);
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tabId").setIndicator("Temp", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.home));
        spec.setContent(intent);

        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        Intent intent1 = new Intent().setClass(this, ActivityStack.class);
        TabHost.TabSpec spec1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("tabId").setIndicator("Temp", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.invoice));
        spec1.setContent(intent1);
        tabHost.addTab(spec1);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
}
```

FirstActivity.java

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("Tab Sample Activity ");
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(getParent(), SecondActivity.class);
                ActivityStack activityStack = (ActivityStack) getParent();
                activityStack.push("SecondActivity", intent);
            }
        });
        setContentView(textView);
    }
}
```

SecondActivity.java

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("First Stack Activity ");
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(getParent(), ThirdActivity.class);
                ActivityStack activityStack = (ActivityStack) getParent();
                activityStack.push("ThirdActivity", intent);
            }
        });
        setContentView(textView);
    }
}
```

ThirdActivity.java

```
public class ThirdActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Add Below XML files into your res/layout folder.

1) tab_screen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="3dp" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</TabHost>
```

2) main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.tabsample"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".FirstActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".TabActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityStack"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SecondActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ThirdActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And see below link for more information with complete example.

[Multiple Android Activities in a TabActivity](http://androidcodeexamples.blogspot.in/2012/08/multiple-android-activities-in.html)

Answer (score 2):

There is two options are available
           1.Activity Group
           2.Fragment
I would like to prefer you fragment because Activity manager is replaced by fragment in the new versions. If you want to use fragment  follow this [link](https://nodeload.github.com/krishjlk/android-fragments-sample-example-tutorial/zip)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a TabActivityGroup to implement it.

From the class which inherits TabActivity, call the activity given below.

```
public class TabActivity extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab_screen);
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, InterMediateActivity.class);
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tabId").setIndicator("Temp", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.home));
        spec.setContent(intent);

        tabHost.addTab(spec);   


        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
}


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class InterMediateActivity extends TabActivityGroup{
    String TabID;
    String TabName;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        filterTabs(TabID);
    }
    private void filterTabs(String TabID)
    {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);                       
            startChildActivity("ContentListing", intent);               



            //TabsUtil.setTabIndicator(specTab,"Wall", null, tabView);

            // TabID
    }



}
```

From this activity you can call another activities as shown in filtertabs function.