# Android TabHost deprecated

Tags: android, android-tabs

I am creating application which will support `Android 2.2` `to Android 4.1`. The `TabHost` is `deprecated in Android version 3.2`. But the created application supported in all the `versions`. But I want to create the `Tab bar` application which will look like a `tab bar` `in Android 4.1` while running the application in `Android 4.2`, If I am running the application in below `android 3.2 version` device, it must look like the `tab bar` in that device. How can I do this.?

Comment: Are you sure TabHost is deprecated? [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html) doesn't says so.

Comment: Hi, How many tab bars can I create using Actionbar.? If more than 10 to 15 means how can I see the last one.

Comment: Hey TabHost is not deprecated. TabActivity got deprecated.

Answer (score 19):

There are many points to your question,

1. `TabHost` is not [deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html) yet. Recently Google deprecated `TabActivity` and `ActivityGroup`.
2. Even if it deprecated, it doesn't mean it can't be used. **If X is deprecated, it only means a better alternative named Y is there.**

Now to answer your question, You have more than one options

1. You can use ActionBarSherlock as other answers suggests. (EDIT : ActionBarSherlock is now deprecated.)
2. You can use `TabHost` with fragments, See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987334/separate-back-stack-for-each-tab-in-android-using-fragments/12928498#12928498) for a
   good example. To use `Fragment` in pre 3.0 API's you need to  use
   [Google's support library.](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html)

Answer (score 6):

Try out [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/).

> ActionBarSherlock is an extension of the support library designed to facilitate the use of the action bar design pattern across all versions of Android with a single API.
>
> The library will automatically use the native action bar when appropriate or will automatically wrap a custom implementation around your layouts. This allows you to easily develop an application with an action bar for every version of Android from 2.x and up.

Tutorials:

[tutorial 1](http://avilyne.com/?p=180) , [tutorial 2](http://xrigau.wordpress.com/2012/03/15/using-an-actionbar-in-your-application-with-actionbarsherlock/) ,
[tutorial 3](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/adding-actionbarsherlock-to-your-project/)

Comment: Yes,I have tried these samples. But i need to create an application with multiple tab views and have to load different URL's into that tab bars.

Comment: you can do everything you said with ActionBarSherlock. You can use Fragments and TabHost as well.

Comment: Oh.OK.How can I create application which will automatically detect the Android Version and the tab bar will be created according to the version.

Comment: ActionBarSherlock handles this automatically. You don't need to check the version. The library will handle it for you.

Comment: Hi, how many tab views can I create using ActionBar.? If I create more than 10 tab bars. How can I create and view those tabs one by one.

Comment: You need to try it out yourself and see for your specific situation. No one can predict this without any code.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add, Android has introduced ActionBarCompat to ensure ActionBar is compatible with OS below 3.0 down to 2.1. You can use ActionBarCompat in the support library instead of ActionBarSherlock

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html