# Android using viewPager vs using tabhost

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tabhost

In my **Android** application I have had to use a **tab layout** and I want to choose a one from folowing scenarios. they are

- using `viewPager`
- using `tab host`

what are the advantages of `viewPager` over `tabhost`. Which one is better. And I'm targeting the **android 4.2**. Thank You!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It actually depends on what you want and the type of content you are putting in application.

**`ViewPager`:**

It is supported in lower API with support library and Sherlock library is always there.
Using `ViewPager` will give a fresh and distinctive feel to the app. For this you'll need to use fragments. Which are complicated but great in terms of performance and are replacable(a superb feature).

[ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)

**TabHost:**

This is achievable using both Fragments and Activities. Although in favour of `FragmentTabHost`, `TabActivity` has been deprecated. However if you are not experienced with Fragments, use Activities, but you can always migrate to fragments later. [FragmentTabHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html)

You should check out different tutorials and implement both of them, then decide. You should learn fragments if you embark on using `ViewPager`. For which, [Check this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/)

[This blog](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-tab-based-applications-series/) has numerous examples of tabs. It can help you decide.

Comment: You are spreading rumours!
Tabhost is not deprecated. see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14272218/1396264
I am using it since I need tabs **inside** my Fragment

Comment: I'ved edited the answer. I know TabHost isn't deprecated. I use it as well. Seems i typed my answer incorrectly back when i posted it. Thanks for correction.

Answer (score 1):

I found it very painful to customize tab host such as increasing indicator height, have to create 9 draw batch and customize background and many things.

With tab layout, only one line of code https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight(int)

So, I recommend using view pager with tab layout that provides the same UX. Tab host is not deprecated, but it will happen soon, I guess :P