# Hide Keyboard when switching tab

Tags: java, android

I have three tabs. On the second one, when I click on the edit text, the keyboard comes up. I want to hide the keyboard whenever I click on the tab1 indicator.

I already dig up the method to hide the keyboard:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
  Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

How can force the keyboard to hide when I switch my tab?

Comment: call this code when the tab change?

Comment: @MarcoAcierno and how do I do that?

Comment: You used ActionBar tabs right?

Comment: mhm I dont think so.  I used tabHost

Comment: `TabHost` is deprecated. It would be a good idea to switch to using `ActionBar` `Tabs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup the listener `OnTabChangeListener` with [`setOnTabChangedListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html#setOnTabChangedListener%28android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener%29) in your [`TabHost`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html), and inside [`TabHost.OnTabChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.OnTabChangeListener.html) add your code block.

Something like this:

```
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId)
    {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(
                Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);

    }
});
```

You can use ActionBar to create tabs anyway

An example:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Your Tab").setTabListener(new ActionBar.TabListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
    {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
                Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
    {

    }
}));
```

[`.addTab()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html#addTab%28android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab%29)
[`.newTab()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html#newTab%28%29)
[`.setTabListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.Tab.html#setTabListener%28android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.TabListener%29)

Comment: You should change `tabHost` with the reference to your TabHost

Comment: What do you mean by deprecated? Is there any difference between TabHost and ActionBar?

Comment: Because since Android 3.0 you can use ActionBar to provide the same features in a better and if you need to use it in versions <= Android 3.0 you can use Support library. I found this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14272125/android-tabhost-deprecated