# Fragment still visible after pressing the back button

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to have a Fragment which provides the ability to create someting.
After that i want to show the new "someting" in another fragment. After pressing the back button on the device i want to go back to the MainFragment and not to the CreateFragment (this works well). But after that the ShowFragment is still visible.

Here is my code:

In my `MainActivity` i got a `MainFragment` which has a button "Create".

After tap the button i load a "Create" Fragment.

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
           .replace(R.id.container, CreateFragment.newInstance())
           .addToBackStack("Create")
           .commit();
```

If the user has entered some details he taps the "Ok" Button. This fires the following on the MainActivity.

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, ShowFragment.newInstance(id))
            .commit();
```

**So far so good, but here comes the problem.**

If the user taps the back button on the device he gets back to the MainFragment BUT the `ShowFragment` is still visible (under the `MainFragment`).

### Update

This is what happens:

MainFragment > CreateFragment > ShowFragment > (BACK Button) > MainFragment (ShowFragment in the back)

Comment: Just remove the line `.addToBackStack("Create")` and you will not again redirected to `CreateFragment`. Its showing the `CreateFragment` because you have added that fragment into stack.

Comment: I dont get back to the CreateFragment. I got back to the MainFragment (this is what i want). But the ShowFragment is sill visible.

Comment: What is `id` in line `ShowFragment.newInstance(id)` ?

Comment: This is just the id of the new "something" (an argument)

Comment: How about removing from R.id.container on back press manually?

Comment: @DoctororDrive Is this the right way?

Comment: Just write `popBackStack()` onbackpress event.

Comment: @dknaack I've never used a backstack feature so I can't really tell if this is the best way.

Comment: but the backstack is filled up with transaction. So when you press back you should not call replace

Answer (score 1):

Just pop the `ShowFragment` from the stack on the `onBackPress` Event as below:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    final Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.container);
    if (fragment != null) {
        fragmentManager.popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Press the back button of fragment `ShowFragment` within your `ShowFragment` fragment will call the `onBackPressed()` method. Then when you call method `popBackStack()`, it will return you back to the `CreateFragment`.

**Sample code** -

```
public void onBackPressed()
{
  FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
  fm.popBackStack();
}
```

See the post [how-to-back-to-previous-fragment-on-pressing-manually-back-button-of-indivisual-fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14275627/how-to-back-to-previous-fragment-on-pressing-manually-back-button-of-indivisual) for more info with similar situation.

Comment: Reason for downvote. What's wrong in the code if it can help.

Comment: 1) This code does pretty the same that the Activity onBackPressed() default implementation and requires Fragment modification and explicit calling. 2) The explanation is pretty unclear, it starts with "Press the back button of fragment " but the Fragment itself does not have/handle the back button.

Comment: See the OP's update - `ShowFragment > (BACK Button)`. The fragment clearly has the back button. The explicit calling is how you can do to go back of stack once you commit in a transaction.

Comment: I'm sure the OP means "ShowFragment is shown and then the back button of the Activity is pressed".