# How to go the previous fragment on the click of the back button of phone in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-button

I want to go back to the previous fragment.I tried many method like `addtobackstack(null)` and all. But I did not get the solution. My problem is when I click on the back button it goes to the home fragment. But I did not want it. I want that when I click on the back button it go to the previous fragment. Can anyone tell me how can I do this ?

This is my `onActivityCreated()` method :-

```
 @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                    if (i == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

                        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                        return true;


                    }


                    return false;
                }
            });

        }
```

This is the first Fragment :-

```
 Fragment fragment = new Packages();
 getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

This is the second fragment :-

```
  Fragment fragment = new DeliveryFrag();
 mContext.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.container, fragment).addToBackStack(null)
                            .commit();
```

This is the third Fragment :-

```
Fragment fragment = new paytm();
   getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                        .replace(R.id.container, fragment).addToBackStack(null)
                                        .commit();
```

I am doing the get the view and apply set `onClickListner` on it. but the program not enter in this method. I don't know why? Please can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to go back to previous fragment on pressing manually back button of individual fragment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14275627/how-to-go-back-to-previous-fragment-on-pressing-manually-back-button-of-individu)

Comment: @Ironman i did not get the solution from that link. thatswhy i am asking again. if you know the answer please tell me.

Comment: Please tell us how are you navigating (example: Home > fragment A > fragment B > ...)

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley i am doing navigating like Home> fragment A > fragment B > fragment C and i want to to go from fragment C to fragment B. but in my case i am going to C to Home instead of fragment B.

Comment: ok, can you please add in the answer the code you are using to go from A to B and from B to C?

Comment: @aarav try replacing the ".replace(containerId, fragment)" with ".add(conainerId, fragment)" and remove the "addToBackStack(null)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should call this method in onResume. like this:

```
 @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        getView().requestFocus();
        getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

                    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to save fragment in stack using `fragmentManager.addToBackStack(<fragment tag>).commit();`. Then try to do `getFragmentManager().popBackStack();`

Answer (score 0):

Make all public `Fragment` like so

```
public Fragment currentFrag = null;
public Fragment f1 = new Packages();
public Fragment f2 = new DeliveryFrag();
public Fragment f3 = new paytm();
```

Then, on the button where changing `Fragment`, fill your null `currentFrag` with the next one

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v){

if(currentFrag == null || currentFrag == f1){
   //open second fragment code
   currentFrag = f2;
   }else if(currentFrag == f2){
   //open third fragment code
   currentFrag = f3;
   }
}
```

then you override the `onBackPressed()` method in your main activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
  if (currentFrag == f1){
  super.onBackPressed() // close the app
  }else if(currentFrag == f2){
  //calling your first fragment code
  currentFrag = null;
  }else if(currentFrag == f3){
  //calling your second fragment code
  currentFrag = f2;
  }
}
```

I hope this helps because even I'm getting a bit confused

Answer (score 0):

**worked for me....you can try this..... may help you...**

```
write addToBackStack(null) before commit();
```

and write following code in your **onBackPressed()** method.

```
  FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
        ApplicationLog.Log(TAG,"IN > 1");
        fm.popBackStack(); //will redirect you previous visited fragment
    }
    else if(fm.getBackStackEntryCount()==1)
    {
      finish(); //will close application
    }
```