# How to create an ActionBar for a FrameLayout?

Tags: android

If I have 2 fragments, Fragment1 and Fragment2. How can I go back to Fragment1 from Fragment2 by using ActionBar?
Below is my activity_main.xml

**ActivityMain.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.android.p2q4.MainActivity">

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: there are many SO posts for this task. please check out. one of them is > https://stackoverflow.com/a/28710049/4566952

Answer (score 0):

Call `setNavigationIcon()` and then `setNavigationIconOnClickListener` and in the `OnClick()` set up the code for going to the previous fragment.

*Note: You must use Toolbar for this.*

Comment: @yoyo97 If fragments have their own layout you can embed toolbars into them. Or just use LinearLayout as parent and add tooblar and FrameLayout as its childs.