# Android Studio - How to manage onBackPressed event?

Tags: android, onbackpressed

**Description:**

I have an activity (*Activity A*) with a button that changes to another activity (Activity B) which has another 3 buttons. Button A goes to *Fragment A*, Button B goes to *Fragment B* and Button C goes to *Fragment C*. I am overriding **onBackPressed method**:

**Question:**

How can I manage onBackPressed method in order you can´t go back to *Activity A* (which is a **login** activity) but can go back, for example, from fragment C to B?

**Edit:**

I am using the following script to go back between fragments:

```
getActivity().onBackPressed();
```

Comment: Hello thomas, all you need is to manage fragmentbackstack. Checkout link below:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14275627/how-to-go-back-to-previous-fragment-on-pressing-manually-back-button-of-individu

Answer (score 0):

You can remove an activity from the history stack. You can achieve this by setting the `android:noHistory` attribute to "true" on Activity A.

```
<activity
    android:name=".Activity_A"
    android:noHistory="true" />
```

but if this is a particular case you can launch your activity A from other Activity D in this way

```
//From activity D
val intent = Intent(this, Activity_A.class)
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)
startActivity(intent)
```

Other way to remove Activity_A from stack is calling `finish()` after launch your Activity B