# How to make particular tab in FragmentTabHost has multiple fragment navigations like tabgroupactivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I created three tabs using FragmentTabHost. Now I need to make all the navigation are under the tabs. How can I get this. I need to get what we get using TabGroupActivity.

Tab1
   --->frag1-->frag2

Tab2
   --->frag3

Tab3
   --->frag4--->frag5

I have used fragmentTransaction.add(), fragmentTransaction.remove(), fragmentTransaction.replace(). These three methods but nothing give solution.

**Replace**  method shows new fragment view on top of existing fragment view.

**Remove** and **Add**, from these two remove only works, add does not works.

Thanks in advance.

TabHostMain.java

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bottom_tabs);

mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
                mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);
            View view;
    view=getTabView(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("key", "Simple");
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator(view),Fragment1.class, null);

    b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("key", "Contacts");
    view=getTabView(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("contacts").setIndicator(view), Fragment2.class, null);

    b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("key", "Custom");
    view=getTabView(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("custom").setIndicator(view),Fragment3.class, null);

}
```

Fragment3.java

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view=LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.activity_second, null);

        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.second_act_text)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager fm=getChildFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fm.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.second_activity, new Fragment1()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: Can get solution from this demo application. https://github.com/iamjayanth/FragmentTabStudy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept of different fragment navigation stacks in each tab has been discussed quite a few times on stackoverflow, one example for instance:

[Separate Back Stack for each tab in Android using Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987334/separate-back-stack-for-each-tab-in-android-using-fragments)

One simple/crude way of achieving this without having to manage your own custom navigation back stack is to have a root fragment under each tab, and then whenever a root fragment wants to navigate to another fragment (fragment B) simply show a new [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) initially with fragment B and that Activity will have its own fragment navigation back stack.

Tab1 --->root frag1 --> Activity (own nav back stack) --> frag2

Tab2 --->root frag3

Tab3 --->root frag4 --> Activity (own nav back stack) --> frag5 --> frag6 --> frag7

An example of an app that does something like this is actually the [StackAnywhere](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rectangularsoftware.stackanywhere&hl=en) app. It makes heavy use of tabs, but when you navigate within those tabs it generally moves the navigation to a new Activity. YMMV with this approach, however.