# In FragmentTabhost, the fragment can`t destory which called by beginTransaction().replace

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-tab-host

My **fragmentTabhost** include 4 `fragments(FragmentA,FragmentB,FragmentC,FragmentD)` in the FragmentTabhost .

In FragmentA, I use the code:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, Fragment_a1).commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

to jump to the **Fragment_a1**(not in the tabhost).

But I found a bug when switching the fragment.Such like this order: 
`FragmentA->Fragment_a1->FragmentB->FragmentA` .

When switch to the **FragmentA** after this order,the screen shows the **Fragment_a1** (It should show the FragmentA). Printing the logcat I found the **Fragment_a1** can`t be destoryed when switch to **FragmentB**.

Please give me a hand .Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I have another method to solve this problem  after reading the answer  @   [How to make particular tab in FragmentTabHost has multiple fragment navigations like tabgroupactivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16558193/how-to-make-particular-tab-in-fragmenttabhost-has-multiple-fragment-navigations)