# Multiple fragment issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

Please have a look at below image

[image]

In left panel there are 2 categories named Ticket and Audit, each with a back button.
Ticket has 2 `ListView's`. If I click any item in 1st `Listview`, it will open 2nd `Listview`.
At the same time, if I click back, again I shall see 1st `Listview`. Again back, will quit application.

This scenario is same for Audits.

For this scenario, I have taken 4 `Fragment's`.

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/framelayout_fragment1_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.7">



</FrameLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/detailFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.mobinius.fragments.DetailFragment" 
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    />
```

There is a flip animation when I switch between Ticket to Audit and vice-versa.

```
private void flipFragments(String tag) {

    System.out.println(" tag in flipFragments : "+tag);
    Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);

    System.out.println(" fragment in flipFragments : "+fragment);       

    if (fragment != null) 
    {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack(tag, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        return;
    }       

    getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()

    .setCustomAnimations(
            R.animator.card_flip_right_in, R.animator.card_flip_right_out,
            R.animator.card_flip_left_in, R.animator.card_flip_left_out)

    .replace(R.id.framelayout_fragment1_container, new AuditGroupFragment(), tag)

    .addToBackStack(tag)

    .commit();        
}
```

When I press back button, replacing Fragment from back stack

```
public void onBack(String tag) {        

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
    if(fragment != null)
        fragmentManager.popBackStack(tag, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    else
        finish();
}
```

When I click any of the list item, replacing current fragment with required

```
public void onListItemClick(String tag, Fragment fragmentToAdd) {       

    getFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()

    .replace(R.id.framelayout_fragment1_container, fragmentToAdd, tag)

    .addToBackStack(tag)

    .commit();
}
```

For Ticket naivigation, both fragments work perfectly.

**Issue :**

By default, Ticket Fragment will be added to Activity. Now, If I switch to Audit, select 1 list item, then switch to Ticket, its taking some time to load and when I again switch back to Audit, I cant see 2nd ListView (it should have been stored in back stack). Its loading from start (showing 1st ListView).

So, first of all is this approach correct? If not please suggest the correct approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got solution for my issue. There is a nice sample example for the same [here](https://github.com/iamjayanth/FragmentTabStudy). Also, its discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987334/separate-back-stack-for-each-tab-in-android-using-fragments/12928498#12928498).