# Implement Tabs with multiple fragments in each tab with seperate back stack

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments, fragment-tab-host

I want to use **multiple fragments in each tab of Tab Host**.
I am googling for last 5 days but nothing is working in my case. I got a good working solution 
[Seperate Back Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12928498/1179638) and [Sample Project Here](https://github.com/iamjayanth/FragmentTabStudy) .This maintain a separate Custom Back Stack for each tab having lots of fragments and store Fragment object in Custom Stack. But when ever I want to re-add any fragment that I already created and stored in its custom stack(as an object), all it's life cycle methods are called once again as are called first time. This is the problem. In this case all the views of fragment layout are recreated and it behaves like a new fragment. 
I want to implement functionality like tabs having activity group(in which lots of activities are combined in a single tab using activity group) with the help of fragments.

Please help me in solving this issue........