# How do I save the state of tabs?

Tags: java, android

In my app, you use the interface in each tab. But when you change tabs, then return it does not save. How do I implement this?

Main Activity

```
 ActionBar.Tab tab1, tab2;
Fragment fragmentTab1 = new FragmentTab1();
Fragment fragmentTab2 = new FragmentTab2();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_screen);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    assert actionBar != null;
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    final ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    bar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);


    tab1 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Skate Dice");
    tab2 = actionBar.newTab().setText("S.K.A.T.E");

    tab1.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(fragmentTab1));
    tab2.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(fragmentTab2));

    actionBar.addTab(tab1);
    actionBar.addTab(tab2);
```

Tab Listener

```
public class MyTabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener
{
Fragment fragment;

public MyTabListener(Fragment fragment)
{
    this.fragment = fragment;
}

public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
{
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
}

public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
{
    ft.remove(fragment);
}

public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
{
    // nothing done here
}
```

}

How do I save the state of my tabs when, the user unselects then comes back to the tab?
I am new to Android Development any advice/help will be much appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987334/separate-back-stack-for-each-tab-in-android-using-fragments) and also check out [this project](https://github.com/SebastianBaltesObjectCode/PersistentFragmentTabs)

Those will hopefully set you on the right direction. Another helpful item to look into is managing the [fragment life cycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle). This can give you the ability to do something with the data before the fragment is paused or destroyed (such as save it).

EDIT:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.TabListener.html gave some good information. Instead of removing your fragment completely, use the attach() and detach() methods. Something like:

```
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if (fragment == null) {
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment); // or use ft.add()
        } else {
            ft.attach(fragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if (mFragment != null) {
            ft.detach(mFragment);
        }
    }
```

I haven't been able to test it yet but it should be along those lines...
Sorry for another link, but [this is helpful too.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest answer - every tab needs to have his own TabListener, so fragment of each tab is saved In TabListener implementation.