# Tabs with Listview in fragments

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I am beginner in android. 
I was having a requirement similar to what is discussed here:
 [Separate Back Stack for each tab in Android using Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987334/separate-back-stack-for-each-tab-in-android-using-fragments/24949948#24949948).

Now, I am using that project given here [gitHub](https://github.com/iamjayanth/FragmentTabStudy)

What I want is to add listview to a fragment..Further on clicking a particular item in list another fragment is visible.

But I am facing a problem in doing it. 
For eg here,I get error in using setListAdapter(adapter) function.
Plz help.

```
public class AppTabAFirstFragment extends BaseFragment {
private Button mGotoButton;
//private String[] characters= {"shs","sds","sdss","sdsd"};
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view       =   inflater.inflate(R.layout.app_tab_a_first_screen, container, false);
    mGotoButton =   (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.id_next_tab_a_button);
    mGotoButton.setOnClickListener(listener);
   // ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(inflater.getContext(),R.layout.app_tab_d_first_screen, characters);
   // setListAdapter(adapter);

    return view;

}
```

In this way,it doesn't allow us to use setListAdapter() function reason being I can't extend ListActivity. I am all confused.
Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't checked your links, but as I can see from the little code you posted I think this might be the problem:

You need to lookup your listview from the xml file (if you have defined it there) and set the adapter to that object. For instance:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_list_view);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: No... Its not helping. After using it I am getting an Null pointer exception

W/dalvikvm(1983): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa6276288)
E/AndroidRuntime(1983): java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:392)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2267)
at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1244)
at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1156)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)

Comment: have you change id of list view in xml? @android:id/list to @+id/my_list_view

Comment: also Replace inflater.getContext() to getActivity() in Adapter Declaration.

Comment: Looking at the error log you posted now (it could have been helpful from the start) is that there is an error with your adapter. I do not know how you implemented your layout (R.layout.app_tab_d_first_screen), but try using the android standard android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 instead and se if it works. Have you uncommented the object characters? If it doesn't work post your full error log

Comment: @Zezeq wohhooo... just now Early morning I tried this (R.layout.simple_list_item_1)and it worked.
Made my day :D :P
Thanks a lot.