# Android : Return to previous fragment on back press

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack, android-navigation

I have implemented Navigation Drawer which is a subclass of Activity. I have many fragments in my application. My question goes here

Imagine there are 3 fragments :

Fragment_1 : Fragment_2 : Fragment_3

When I start my application, Fragment_1 is loaded
When I click on some components on Fragment_1, I'm navigated to Fragment_2 and so on..

So it's like

Fragment_1 > Fragment_2 > Fragment_3

When I press back key from Fragment_2, I'm navigated back to Fragment_1
But when I press back key from Fragment_3, I'm navigated back to Fragment_1 (instead of Fragment_2)

I want something like this in my application on Back Key press

Fragment_1 < Fragment_2 < Fragment_3

I have used Fragment, FragmentManager, FragmentTransaction as follows :

```
MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).addToBackStack(null)commit();
```

and I tried overriding onBackPressed() in my MainActivity :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {


        getFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
        if (count == 0)
               super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Answer (score 36):

Update your `Activity#onBackPressed()` method to:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

The reason your implementation doesn't work is because the method `FragmentManager#popBackStack()` is asynchronous and does not happen right after it is called.

From the documentation:

> This function is asynchronous -- it enqueues the request to pop, but the action will not be performed until the application returns to its event loop.

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack(java.lang.String,%20int)

Comment: Your code works for some part. Problem is that :: 
Suppose I navigate as follows >> Fragment_1 > Fragment_2 > Fragment_3 , and then from navigation drawer I select again Fragment_1 and navigate same as below and later on press back key, I find following sequence Fragment_1 < Fragment_2 < Fragment_3 < Fragment_1 < Fragment_2 < Fragment_3

Comment: You are getting this sequence because each `FragmentManager` operation  that you are doing is being added to the back stack through `FragmentTransaction#addToBackStack()`. I read again your question and still don't know what you are expecting in this case. Please clarify.

Comment: actually your code solved my issue. But how to change following sequence :: Fragment_1 < Fragment_2 < Fragment_3 < Fragment_1 < Fragment_2 < Fragment_3 __to__ Fragment_1 < Fragment_2 < Fragment_3..... Irrespective of the user's repeated action as Fragment_1 > Fragment_2 > Fragment_3. If you are still not getting my point, then other term for my problem is to remove redundancy of same fragments

Comment: I guess what you are planning to do is to avoid duplicated entries in the `FragmentManager` and the Back stack, right? If so, you can check if a `Fragment` is already in the stack by setting a TAG when you commit it and them searching for it (with `FragmentManager#findFragmentByTag(String TAG)` and not calling `addToBackStack()` if it doesn't return a null value. Also please mark my response as the answer to the question if it solved your problem.

Comment: Can you illustrate with short example ? (code for findFragmentByTag(...) )

Answer (score 3):

You have to implement your own backstack implementation as explained here

[Separate Back Stack for each tab in Android using Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987334/separate-back-stack-for-each-tab-in-android-using-fragments/12928498#12928498)

You can call the popFragments() whenever you click the back button in a fragment and call pushFragments() whenever you navigate from one Fragment to other.

in Short,

```
public void onBackPressed()
{
    FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    fm.popBackStack();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The tric is in `FragmentManager#executePendingTransactions();`.

This is what I use for nested fragments as well...:

```
/**
 * if there is a fragment and the back stack of this fragment is not empty,
 * then emulate 'onBackPressed' behaviour, because in default, it is not working.
 *
 * @param fm the fragment manager to which we will try to dispatch the back pressed event.
 * @return {@code true} if the onBackPressed event was consumed by a child fragment, otherwise
 */
public static boolean dispatchOnBackPressedToFragments(FragmentManager fm) {

    List<Fragment> fragments = fm.getFragments();
    boolean result;
    if (fragments != null && !fragments.isEmpty()) {
        for (Fragment frag : fragments) {
            if (frag != null && frag.isAdded() && frag.getChildFragmentManager() != null) {
                // go to the next level of child fragments.
                result = dispatchOnBackPressedToFragments(frag.getChildFragmentManager());
                if (result) return true;
            }
        }
    }

    // if the back stack is not empty then we pop the last transaction.
    if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        fm.popBackStack();
        fm.executePendingTransactions();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

and in my `onBackPressed` :

```
                if (!FragmentUtils.dispatchOnBackPressedToFragments(fm)) {
                    // if no child fragment consumed the onBackPressed event,
                    // we execute the default behaviour.
                    super.onBackPressed();
                }
```

Comment: Very useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code on tab change in your main activity to clear the stack.

```
int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
        if(count>0){
            for (int i = 0; i <count; i++) {
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            }
        }
```

Then on Back pressed of your main activity do this

```
 int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

     if (count == 0) {
         super.onbackpressed();
        }
else {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is working and tested code by me, This will help you

```
 private static final int TIME_INTERVAL = 2000;
private long mBackPressed;
 private void applyExit() {
    if (mBackPressed + TIME_INTERVAL > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        finish();
    } else {
         Toast.makeText(this,"Press Again to exit",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    mBackPressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    if (fm.getFragments().size() <= 1) {
        applyExit();
    } else {
        for (Fragment frag : fm.getFragments()) {
            if (frag == null) {
                applyExit();
                return;
            }
            if (frag.isVisible()) {
                FragmentManager childFm = frag.getChildFragmentManager();
                if (childFm.getFragments() == null) {
                    super.onBackPressed();
                    return;
                }
                if (childFm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                    childFm.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                    return;
                } else {
                    fm.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```