# How to add nested fragment to backstack inside a tabbed view pager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-view, android-tablayout

My app contains two tabs, inside two tabs every tab has 4-5 nested fragments, inside nested fragments addtobackstack is not working?
How can I add nested fragments to backstack because when I click back button inside nested fragments my app is closing means it's calling super.onBackKeyPressed method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this code in your activity

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (fm.getFragments() != null) {
        for (Fragment frag : fm.getFragments()) {
            if (frag.isVisible()) {
                FragmentManager chilFrag = frag.getChildFragmentManager();
                if (chilFrag.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                    chilFrag.popBackStack();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
     }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use ChildFragmentManager

This is fragment replace function.

```
fun replace(fragment: Fragment){
  childFragmentManager
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
    .commit()
}
```

And override onBackPressed method in most parent fragment.

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
val pop = childFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate()
if (!pop){
  super.onBackPressed()
}
```

}

I wrote with kotlin i hope you can understand.If you need more info, please ask to me.

Comment: Can you elaborate more?

Comment: should I use inside viewpager or nested fragments?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ChildFragmentManager` and check if active tab has `BackStackEntry`, if so then pop backstack else call `super.onBackKeyPressed`

complete description on this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37961649/4832356