# Instagram type backstack navigation Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, back-stack, fragment-backstack

How to implement navigation like instagram where every tab of theirs has it's own back stack?

I have a TabLayout with 5 tabs and I inflate many different fragments in each tab individually depending on user action but it all just gets added to the backStack in general, not specifically to each tab.

For example in my:
If I am in the **Settings Tab**-->**Inflate User Frag**-->**Inflate Profile Pic Frag**

Then I go to the **Feed Tab**-->**Open Post Frag**

Then I go back to the **Settings Tab**, the **Profile Pic frag** will still be open which is good but if I click the back button I would like it to remove the **Profile Pic frag** and take me back to the **User Frag** but instead it will remove the **Open Post Frag**

I've played around with FragmentTransactions and the backstack but can't seem to get it right, often the problem is too many fragments get removed when I dont want them to.

Any help will be great!

Comment: got answer ? if yes please help me. stuck in same

Comment: @BincyBaby there is not Android-like. I know it's a cool feature and all, but Google hasn't designed it this way. You will probably have to implement your own backstack, which will also have to restore in case your Activity gets recreated. I once implemented it by using `ArrayList<Fragment<Stack>> mListOfTabStacks`. Each element of this list contained the stack of that tab. It's a bad way as I didn't know much back then.

Comment: Related: [Separate Back Stack for each tab in Android using Fragments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987334/separate-back-stack-for-each-tab-in-android-using-fragments). A solution similar to what I said is there in one of the answers, but please read **hackbod**'s answer as well, she's Android Framework engineer.

Comment: Check this implementation, should suit your needs - https://medium.com/@smihajlovskih/create-instagram-like-backstack-4711600c5bff