# Maintaining HashMap of Fragment Stack on screen rotation

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, serialization, bottomnavigationview

I have in my activity a `BottomNavigationView`. I am trying to create a separate backstack for each item of `BottomNavigationView`. I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45630249/4961540) answer to do the same but I am having problem saving the `HashMap` `mStacks` on screen rotation. As `HashMap` is serializable, I saved it in the `outState` bundle provided in `onSaveInstanceState` function but I got the error that one of the fragment lets say `MyFragment` in my app is not `Serializable` so what I did was implemented `Serializable` for `MyFragment`, but again I got the error that the `FragmentAdapter` present inside `MyFragment` is not serializable. Now I can't think of any way to save `mStacks` on screen rotation. Do you know any way to do so? Please help me

Comment: You need both the Key and the Value of the HashMap to be serializable too.  Neither Stack nor Fragment implement the serializable interface.  You may be able to extend these classes & implement Serializable to get what you need.

Comment: @Gary99 Yes that is the reason I implemented serializable for fragment but the fragment which I am trying to serialize has FragmentAdapter and that is not serializable.

Comment: MyFragmentAdapter extends FragmentAdapter implements Serializable {}?

Comment: @Gary99 Oh, I thought the `FragmentPagerAdapter` provided by android was Unserializable, but as a second thought, will saving all Fragment stack be efficient ?

Comment: Sorry, not sure.

Comment: No problem, thank you for the help anyways :)

Comment: well why don't we store only positions accordingly and then get it via bundle on other side after rotation. ?

Comment: and rest of the data can be saved in model which can be serializable and can be easily retrieved after screen rotation using again bundle.

Comment: Yes, I thought of it few minutes back. I will try it.