# Separate Back Stack for each tab in Android Navigation Component

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation, fragment-backstack

I'm creating a shopping application using Navigation Component(NavHost with BottomNavigationView) 
The app has two tabs(Tab Home & Tab Categories). From Tab Home, the user can select a product and see the product detail and from Tab Categories, the user can navigate through categories. Now when the user opens a product from Tab Home, then if he/she selects Tab Category and then he/she selects Tab Home again, the Home destination will show but I want to show product destination and when the user clicks on back button show him/her home destination. 
I've read these questions([Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987334/separate-back-stack-for-each-tab-in-android-using-fragments) , [Question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45611300/separate-back-stack-for-each-tab-in-bottomnavigationview-android-using-fragments)) but they don't use NavHost. I want to know is there any simpler or automatic way to accomplish this in NavHost?

Comment: it a bit unclear

Comment: @John Joe I want to do something like this with NavHost https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45611300/separate-back-stack-for-each-tab-in-bottomnavigationview-android-using-fragments

Comment: @hosseinAmini chack this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42362917/fragment-re-created-on-bottom-navigation-view-item-selected